# How to filter / exclude posts by id in list of posts in WordPress Dashboard / Admin

Tags: wordpress, list, dashboard, posts

So, what I am trying to do is filter the list of posts (mine is actually a custom post type) in the WordPress Dashboard by ID.

I am checking another area (custom widget) to see if the user can edit a given post (not, I am intentionally dodging the WordPress roles, etc), if they cannot I want to filter/exclude that post from the list.

I want to take this list:

See Image: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-nQLDUpoHUig/T84sUXwqNDI/AAAAAAAAB1o/fzZvCkSjawI/w678-h533-k/list_of_posts.PNG

...and filter out post ID's that another function returns

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, could you give an example?

Comment: See my edits to the original post. Hope that helps clear up what I am trying to do...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I've answered my own question. Here is some code on how I did it.

```
function exclude_list_per_function( $query ) {

    global $wpdb;

    //gets all the post ID's, I know this is a bit of a hack
    $querystr = "
        SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID
        FROM $wpdb->posts
    "; $post_ids = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

        //Go through each post and pass it to a function that returns true if the user_can, and false if the user_can't
        foreach($post_ids as $post_obj){
            if(!can_user_other_function_view_this_post(get_post($post_obj->ID))){
                //if they_can't, add them to the array to be excluded
                $posts_not_in[]=$post_obj->ID;
            }
        }

        //Set those posts to be excluded from the list.
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $posts_not_in );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_list_per_function');
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out, sorry for being too slow :)